# How to find preorder traversal from given postorder traversal of binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a post-order traversal of a BST like [3,6,5,1,12,16,15,10,20,7] and I want to find its pre-order traversal like [7,1,5,3,6,20,10,15,12,16].
Is it possible to find a recursive solution without constructing the tree? [Edited]

Comment: Do you mean "without using recursion" or "while using a recursive solution"?

Comment: I mean I want to use recursion.

Comment: No need to add [edited]. It is reflected below the post already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function without building the tree. It traverses the post order list from the end to the beginning, since that represents *almost* the required order, with the exception that children are visited in opposite order:

```
def preordered(postorder):
    def recur(granny, parent):
        if not postorder or postorder[-1] < min(granny, parent):
            return []
        value = postorder.pop()
        right = recur(parent, value)
        left = recur(parent, value)
        return [value] + left + right

    low = min(postorder)
    postorder = postorder[:]
    return recur(low, low)

result = preordered([3,6,5,1,12,16,15,10,20,7])
```